# Python continuously read a websocket.recv()

Tags: python, websocket

beginner python programmer here. I'm trying to write a WebSocket client code but I am having trouble continuously reading the recv. I am trying to get the server to be able to send multiple messages without having a user input from the client side. Here's my current code:

```
import websockets
import asyncio

        while msg != "end":
            msg = input("\nMessage here: ")

            await websocket.send(msg)
            print(f"> {msg}")

            if msg!= "end":

                reply = await websocket.recv()
                print(f"< {reply}")
        print("goodbye")
```

Is there a way to continuously receive a reply without having a user input at client side?